# How the kernel different subsystems share CPU time

Tags: linux-kernel, resources, operating-system, kernel, scheduled-tasks

Processes in userspace are scheduled by the kernel scheduler to get processor time but how the different kernel tasks get CPU time? I mean, when no process at userspace are requering CPU time (so CPU is iddle by executing NOP instructions) but some kernel subsystem need to carry out some task regularly, are timers and other hw and sw interrupts the common methods to get CPU time in kernel space?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same scheduler. The only difference I could think of is that kernel code has much more control over execution flow. For example, there is direct call to scheduler [`schedule()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c?v=3.15#L2750).

Also in kernel you have 3 execution contexts - hardware interrupt, softirq/bh and process. In hard (and probably soft) interrupt context you can't sleep, so scheduling is not done during executing code in this context.

Comment: I dont understand how the same scheduler schedule kernel tasks. Are there processes running instructions from the kernel space waiting in the queues to be scheduled? how this kernel processes are created?

Comment: Scheduler works with entities of `struct tast_struct`. Every time you create new process (via `fork` or ultimately `clone`), create thread (`pthread_create`) or create kernel_thread (`kthread_create`) there will be created corresponding `task_struct`. Scheduler operates on this structs and that's it. Seems like you're confused with kernel and userspace execution and so I'd recommend you "Linux kernel development" by Robert Love (chapters on "Process management" and "Process scheduling").